# Как вставить React-компонент с npm-зависимостями в HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, node-modules

Есть лендинг на чистом html + css, понадобилось вставить один компонент, который будет считать стоимость заказа на одну из страничек. Сделал всё как в [документации к реакту](https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#optional-try-react-with-jsx).

Компонент, который пытаюсь вставить имеет зависимости от npm-пакетов `uuidv4` и `axios`, поэтому если я убираю импорты, рендеринг происходит нормально, но как только добавляю импорты, то уже ничего не работает.

Следующий код вставляю в html-разметку:

```
        <script type="text/babel">
          import * as axios from 'axios'
          const e = React.createElement
          const Hello = () => <div>Hello!!!</div>

          const domContainer = document.querySelector('#container')
          ReactDOM.render(e(Hello), domContainer)
        </script>
```

Если закомментировать импорт, то рендерит `Hello!!!`, но с импортом ничего не рендерится.

Comment: ```<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>``` вставить перед исполняемым скриптом